# Trying to access each element from objects part of an array with PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I can't get to list each element's Key and Value from an object which is part of an array.

I've added the objects to an array as you can see from the code, but I just couldn't get the $finalList as wanted.

```
$date = Get-Date
$userInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True'"

$userAccount = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($user in $userInfo) {
    $userAccount += (@{
        "Name"=$user.Name;
        "Status"=$user.Status;
        "Disabled"=$user.Disabled;
        "AccountType"=$user.AccountType;
        "Lockout"=$user.Lockout;
        "PasswordRequired"=$user.PasswordRequired;
        "PasswordChangeable"=$user.PasswordChangeable;
        "SID"=$user.SID;
    })
}

foreach ($item in $userAccount) {
    $temp = New-Object System.Object
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value "$date"
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -Value "$env:computername"
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Key" -Value "$($item.Keys)"
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Value" -Value "$($item.Values)"
    $finalList.Add($temp) | Out-Null
}
```

With the $finalList I want to have a column for the date, for the hostname and two more columns with Keys and Values from $userAccount array. $finalList will be exported to csv.

Comment: Where is the instantiation of `$finalList`?  Is it above this code section?  Otherwise, that appears to be your only issue.

Comment: Indeed, it was part of the issue, but PowerShell will automatically set is as array (although it behaves different compared to a declared array for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me. your code seems to work, asides from the fact that you did not declare the second arraylist.

```bsh
$date = Get-Date
$userInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True'"

$userAccount = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($user in $userInfo) {
    $userAccount += (@{
        "Name"=$user.Name;
        "Status"=$user.Status;
        "Disabled"=$user.Disabled;
        "AccountType"=$user.AccountType;
        "Lockout"=$user.Lockout;
        "PasswordRequired"=$user.PasswordRequired;
        "PasswordChangeable"=$user.PasswordChangeable;
        "SID"=$user.SID;
    })
}


$finalList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($item in $userAccount) {
    $temp = New-Object System.Object
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value "$date"
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -Value "$env:computername"
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Key" -Value "$($item.Keys)"
    $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Value" -Value "$($item.Values)"
    $finalList.Add($temp) | Out-Null
}


$finalList | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\file.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: PowerShell will automatically declare it as an array list, but is better to have it declared, because for some reason it is not behaving the same even though $finalList.GetType() will produce the same results. By adding another loop ($item.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {) in the foreach ($item in $userAccount) { I am getting the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell will automatically set $finalList as an array list, but is better to have it declared, because for some reason it is not behaving the same even though $finalList.GetType() will produce the same results. Enumerating the hashstable $item will allow me to grab the key/value pairs as wanted.

```
$finalList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($item in $userAccount) {
    $item.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        $temp = New-Object System.Object
        $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value "$date"
        $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -Value "$env:computername"
        $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Key" -Value $_.Key
        $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Value" -Value $_.Value
        $finalList.Add($temp) | Out-Null
    }
}

$finalList
```